# how to add a piece of text at the beginning of a line

Tags: vim

In my text file I have a line which goes `:some text`

I want to add another text `some other text` to the beginning of the first line so that line now looks `some other text:some text`. I have been trying with yanking the required text and moving cursor just before `:some text` using the `p` command, but the copied text appears in the line above `:some text`.

I was wondering if there is some way of doing the same.

Also it would be good if there is a method to select multiple pieces of text and put it at beginning of multiple lines. For instance if file reads:

```
some text 

some other text

line1 

line2
```

I want to select `line1` and `line2` and put it in the beginning of `some text` and `some other text` so it will look like

```
line1 some text

line2 some other text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Block select (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) the `line 1` and `line 2` lines
2. Go to line `some text` and past it before the cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>/`P`)

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

- `I` will enter insertion mode at the beginning of the line
- `^` will move your cursor to the beginning of the line.
- If you want to paste a full line before the text, you can e.g. paste it with `P`, then join the lines with `J`.

For your second question, you can use the "Visual Block" mode:

- Move to the beginning of "some text".
- `Ctrl+V` enters "Visual Block".
- Select a rectangle spanning both lines
- Move to the end of "line1", paste with `p`.

Note that this works well only if "line1" and "line2" have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Joining two consecutive lines: `J`

Inserting text at the begining of a line: `0iyour text here`<kbd>ESC</kbd>

Inserting text just before the first non whitespace of a line: `Iyour text here`<kbd>ESC</kbd>

Comment: `gI` can also be used instead of `0i`.

Answer (score 1):

If you yank a line with `yy` or `Y` the line is yanked including the newline character at the end.
To yank a line without the newline you can use `0y$` (`0` - goto start of line, `y$` - yank to end of line).

Then you can paste it at the beginning of the line you want with `0P`.
`P` means paste before cursor.